# List of software preinstalled in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, system-installation

Is there a complete list of software (not package) preinstalled in Linux Mint?

Comment: What do you mean by “software (not package)”?

Comment: List only with `the-software` (i.e. without `the-software-data` or `the-software-l10n-ru`)